# mod_rewrite always gives 10 internal redirects and fails

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd, php-fpm

I have a simple .htaccess which fails to redirect correctly on some reason:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*$ /test.php [L]
```

There is a log entry:

```
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [error] [client 213.141.155.85] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3053): [client 213.141.155.85] r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /test.php
[Tue Nov 16 17:04:12 2010] [debug] core.c(3059): [client 213.141.155.85] redirected from r->uri = /blabla
```

There URL i'm trying to access is /blabla

It seems to rewrite correctly, but [L] option somehow has no effect. How can that be?

virtual host is configured like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mx-key.ru
ServerAlias mx-key.ru www.mx-key.ru
ServerAdmin FractalizeR@yandex.ru
DocumentRoot /home/mxkey/mx-key.ru/www
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php5 index.php4 index.php3 index.shtml
ErrorLog /home/mxkey/mx-key.ru/logs/httpd_error.log
CustomLog /home/mxkey/mx-key.ru/logs/httpd_access.log "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
LogLevel Debug
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        Options +ExecCGI
        FastCgiExternalServer /home/mxkey/mx-key.ru/www/php-fpm.handler -socket /home/mxkey/php-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 600
        AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
        Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php-fpm.handler
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If I add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php-fpm.handler to the .htaccess it starts to work fine. Any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `RewriteCond` also - your `RewriteRule` is always matching everything (because of `^.*$`). Take a look here:

- http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond

You need to exclude the target of `RewriteRule`, which is `/test.php`.

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test.php$
```

which says something like "rewrite only if the request URI doesn't start with /test.php".

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. I even tried RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ but it also doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I've been missing % - you need %{REQUEST_URI}.